# Dependencies does not inject during weblogic deployment

Tags: java, spring, deployment, dependency-injection, weblogic

I want to deploy my project on weblogic but when I deploy the war, my spring applicationContext gets loaded and when it starts hydrating my caches it crashes giving me a null pointer exception. When I debugged I saw that my persistence entity class, that is used during the method, is instantiated with out its dependencies meaning they did not get injected.

My entity class is marked with @Configurable and the getter and setter methods for the dependencies are marked with @Transient. Also, when I run my tests it does inject the dependencies in the entity class and it seems it does not inject when I am trying to deploy to weblogic. I have no idea where to start looking for the problem thus I have no idea which code I should supply you with.

Any tips on what I should google or where to look into would be much appreciated. Also if you want to have a look at some code just ask and I will add it.

Thank you and I apologize for the lack of code but I have no idea which bit would actually help and which code would be useless.

EDIT:

Adding code
Entity class

```
@Configurable
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "Some_Table")
public class InteractionImpl implements Interaction, Serializable {

    private Long interactionId;
    private Long initiatorEntityNr;
    private Long agentEntityNr;

    transient private BuilderB builderB;
    transient private BuilderA builderA;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "justAnotherID")
    public Long getInteractionId() {
        return interactionId;
    }

    public void setInteractionId(Long interactionId) {
        this.interactionId = interactionId;
    }

    @Column(name = "someCodeB")
    private Long getInitiatorEntityNr() {
        return initiatorEntityNr;
    }

    private void setInitiatorEntityNr(Long initiatorEntityNr) {
        this.initiatorEntityNr = initiatorEntityNr;
    }

    @Column(name = "someCodeA")
    private Long getAgentEntityNr() {
        return agentEntityNr;
    }

    private void setAgentEntityNr(Long agentEntityNr) {

        this.agentEntityNr = agentEntityNr;
    }

    @Transient
    public Agent getAgent() throws CrmEntityCreationException {
        if (getAgentEntityNr() != null)
            return builderA.buildShallowEntity(getAgentEntityNr());
        else
            throw new CrmEntityCreationException("There was no agent entity number so the entity could not be found");
}

    @Transient
    public void setAgent(Agent agentEntity) {
        setAgentEntityNr(agentEntity.getEntityNumber());
    }

    @Transient
    public Customer getInitiator() throws CrmEntityCreationException {
        if (getInitiatorEntityNr() != null) {
            return builderB.buildShallowEntity(getInitiatorEntityNr());
        } else {
            throw new CrmEntityCreationException("The interaction does not contain an initiator entity number");
        }
    }

    @Transient
    public void setInitiator(Customer initiatorEntity) {
        setInitiatorEntityNr(initiatorEntity.getEntityNumber());
    }

    @Transient
    private BuilderB getCustomerBuilder() {
        return builderB;
    }

    @Inject
    @Transient
    public void BuilderB(BuilderB builderB) {
        this.builderB = builderB;
    }

    @Transient
    private BuilderA getBuilderA() {
        return builderA;
    }

    @Inject
    @Transient
    public void setBuilderA(BuilderA builderA) {
        this.builderA = builderA;
    }



}
```

Application Context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"

       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="aspectj"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="crm.persistence"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="crm.services.impl"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>


    <bean id="hazelcast" class="com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast" factory-method="newHazelcastInstance"/>

    <bean id="httpComponentMessageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@someConnection:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="someUsername"/>
        <property name="password" value="somePassword"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
    </bean>

    <bean id="interactionCache" class="crm.services.impl.Caching.InteractionCacheImpl">
        <property name="ammountOfInteractionToReturn" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="interactions" class="crm.persistence.entities.InteractionImpl" scope="prototype"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="interactionCache"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="rehydrateAllCaches"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="agentCache" class="crm.services.impl.Caching.AgentCacheImpl"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="agentCache"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="rehydrateAll"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="alertCache"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="rehydrateAll"/>
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Then my spring webservice servlet

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:applicationContext.xml"/>

    <!--scans for spring-ws annotation-->
   <sws:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

My web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and then my weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <context-root>/CrmService</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

As seen in my application context I have two caches that I rehydrate. The hydrate method calls a DAO to find a list of relevant interactions (Entity class) and then calls the `getAgent()` and `getInitiator()` methods. Since `builderA` and `builderB` does not get injected it throws a null pointer exception.

Just to remind you that it injects these classes in my integration tests but not when I try and deploy it to weblogic. I don't use tomcat

Comment: Does your project work with tomcat or only weblogic? Did you get a relevant stacktrace? I have IntelliJ IDE open ready to help you if we know where to look. Maybe you can have a reference project that works and incrementally change it to your project and see in which change the exception occurs.

Comment: I use intellij, only work with weblogic, I don't believe the stack trace would help much as it only indicates the point where the nullpointer is getting throwed. I will add the code for the entity class, my application context and   maybe my spring webservice servlet.

Comment: I'm installing weblogic to see what I can. I'll get back to you when I got it setup with spring. IIUC you don't use spring boot(?)

Comment: No, what you see is what you get. It seems pretty straight forward. I have had problems deploying it in the first place. I had to get the hibernate-validator-cdi dependency since I kept getting an AbstractMethodError.